# MySQL Combine Four Tables (related) into a new Table so that I can Export to a CSV

Tags: mysql

My goal is to combine all fields from all 4 tables to produce a new table with all fields, so that I can export as a CSV ready for import CSV in to WordPress/WooCommerce.

The 'main' table seems to be SubProducts (with 2000 items) and these all relate to the Products table (20 items), which relate to Categories and Brands. Hope that makes some sense.

I would be grateful for any SQL guidance you are able share.

There are 4 Tables;

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
    CategoryID tinyint NOT NULL,
    BrandID tinyint NOT NULL,
    ChartImage varchar(50) NULL,
    FrontPage bit NULL DEFAULT (0),
    Visibility bit NULL DEFAULT (0),
    Brochure varchar(50) NULL,
    Video varchar(50) NULL,
    SmallImageA varchar(50) NULL,
    MediumImageA varchar(50) NULL,
    LargeImageA varchar(50) NULL,
    SmallImageB varchar(50) NULL,
    MediumImageB varchar(50) NULL,
    LargeImageB varchar(50) NULL,
    SmallImageC varchar(50) NULL,
    MediumImageC varchar(50) NULL,
    LargeImageC varchar(50) NULL,
    SmallImageD varchar(50) NULL,
    MediumImageD varchar(50) NULL,
    LargeImageD varchar(50) NULL,
    SmallImageE varchar(50) NULL,
    MediumImageE varchar(50) NULL,
    LargeImageE varchar(50) NULL,
    LinkA varchar(300) NULL,
    LinkB varchar(300) NULL,
    LinkC varchar(300) NULL,
    LinkD varchar(300) NULL,
    LinkE varchar(300) NULL,
    ProductAssociationA int NULL,
    ProductAssociationB int NULL,
    ProductAssociationC int NULL
);

SubProducts, 
CREATE TABLE SubProducts (
    SubProductID int NOT NULL,
    Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    OnPromotion bit NOT NULL,
    Visibility bit NOT NULL,
    RetailerPrice varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    RetailerPromotionPrice varchar(20) NULL,
    PharmacyPrice varchar(20) NULL,
    PharmacyPromotionPrice varchar(20) NULL,
    GovernmentPrice varchar(20) NULL,
    GovernmentPromotionPrice varchar(20) NULL
);

Categories, 
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    CategoryID tinyint NOT NULL,
    CategoryName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SortColumn tinyint NULL
);

Brands,
CREATE TABLE Brands (
    BrandID tinyint NOT NULL,
    BrandName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SortColumn tinyint NULL
);
```

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Please define what the result should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to dump things would be to join on the obvious keys:

`SELECT Products.*, SubProducts.*, Categories.*, Brands.* FROM
Products
LEFT JOIN SubProducts ON ( Products.ProductID = SubProducts.ProductID )
LEFT JOIN Categories ON ( Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID )
LEFT JOIN Brands ON ( Brands.BrandID = Products.BrandID )
/* This part of the query will give you a CSV file: */
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfilename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Comment: Thank you kmoser - that was exactly what I was looking for. Your time and effort much appreciated.